# Declarations, initializations, instructions in C

Tags: c

I am preparing for an exam about C programming and came across the following question which I am not sure how to answer:

"The following syntactically correct declarations are given. Assume that all variables have been initialized in the subsequent instructions:

```
void *vptr, *wptr;
char *s;
size_t vsize, ssize;
int cmp;
```

Three of these instructions are semantically incorrect and would lead to a compilation error, which?:

1. `vptr++;`
2. `cmp = vptr == wptr;`
3. `vsize = sizeof(*vptr);`
4. `s = wptr;`
5. `s = vptr - 1;`
6. `vptr = malloc(ssize * sizeof *s);`

Somehow when I try to compile these (using the gnu compiler), I never get an error. My guesses however are that 3, 5 and 6 are incorrect because I am trying to get the size of void (3), accessing/assigning memory that has not been allocated (5) and allocating memory without freeing the previous memory (6). I'm rather unsure about my answers, plus I don't get why the compilation worked fine for all these instructions. Does anyone have an explanation?

Comment: All of the issues are related to the fact that the `void` that a `void*` pointer points to has no meaningful size. Try cranking up the warning level (something like -Wall -Wextra -pedantic if you are using gcc or clang).

Comment: thanks, that did the trick!

Comment: "Assume that all variables have been initialized" --- they can't be initialized after their declaration (unless it's another (repeated) declaration). `int i; int i = 42; i = 0;` has a declaration, a definition (declaration + initialization), and an assignment. *add that in your answer for extra points*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nearly correct.

The wrong ones are (a), (c) and (e) (1,3,5, after the edit).

The explanation for all of them is basically the same: (a) and (e) perform pointer arithmetics, this isn't possible on `void *`, because `void` is unknown and doesn't have a size. (c) is similar, `sizeof()` is given a `void` expression, again, `void` doesn't have a size.

Comment: Are you sure "unknown" is correct? I'd say, incomplete type.

Comment: It would be worth while to add why his compiler doesn't show any error - because many compiler extensions treat `void` to be same size as `char` and define `sizeof(void)`. But it is error according to standard

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense! thanks also for explaining why there's no compilation error (@ Ajay)

Answer (score 2):

The wrong ones are: 1,3,5 because

### Arithmetic on a `void*` is illegal in both C and C++.

From the Standard:

> 6.5.6-2: For addition, either both operands shall have arithmetic type, or one operand shall be a pointer to an object type and the
>   other shall have integer type
>
> 6.2.5.1: Types are partitioned into object types (types that fully describe objects) , function types (types that describe functions),
>   and incomplete types (types that describe objects but lack information
>   needed to determine their sizes).
>
> 6.2.5-19: The void type comprises an empty set of values; it is an incomplete type that cannot be completed

`void` is incomplete (**which translates to, the compiler does not know its size**) so by `6.5.6-2` you can't use it in the aforementioned expressions.

Answer (score 1):

```
vptr++
```

is incorrect because vptr is a pointer that points to an object of unknown size, so this expression will be desugared in `vptr+=sizeof(*vptr)` and the type of `*vptr` is void; `sizeof(void)` is undefined as the type is incomplete.  `gcc` considers `sizeof(void)=sizeof(char)=1` but this is gnu extension.

```
vsize = sizeof(*vptr);
```

is not correct as `*vptr` has the type `void` as described above.

```
s = vptr - 1;
```

is also incorrect as the pointer arithmetic means to subtract the `sizeof (typeof(*vptr))`.